# Controlling the number of digits of parameters using optim in r

Tags: r, optimization

I would like to decrease the number of digits for predicted parameters in this example. Any idea?

```
f <- function(par) {  
  a <- par[1]  
  b <- par[2]  
  (a - 1) + 3.2/b + 3*log(gamma(a)) + 3*a*log(b);  
}     

optim(c(1, .3), fn=f)  
# $par  
# [1] 1.399685 0.762025
```

Comment: Do you just want `round`?

Comment: No, I am running a big model and I thought maybe by decreasing the number of digits it takes less time.

Comment: Perhaps look at the `control` arguments to `optim`.